# Slider using dynamic data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

I am trying to have an slider using dynamic data on django which is supposed to slide throw users like in tinder. The slider has 2 buttons, one redirects the user to the previusly seen profile and the other one redirects the user to the next profile, also I need to load the page without reloading it. I am very new to javascript so I dont really know how would the js code end up being, How can I make this work? Please this is very important

html

```
    <div class="mates-grid-1-1-content">
        <div class="mates-grid-2-content">
            <button type="submit" id="prev-button">prev</button>
        </div>
        <div class="mates-grid-1-content">
            <div class="mates-item-content">
                <img class="mate-pic" src="{{ user.profile.profile_pic.url }}" >
            </div>
            <div class="mates-item-content">
                <a href="{% url 'profile' username=content.user.username %}" style="float: left">{{ content.user }}</a>
            </div>
            <div class="mates-item-content">
                <div class="responses">
                    <div class="response-item-img">
                        <img class="mates-image" src="{{ content.req_image.url }}" width="400px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="response-item-bio">
                        <p>{{ content.req_bio }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="response-item-button">
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mates-grid-3-content">
            <button type="submit" id="next-button">next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

models.py

```
    class Mates(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='usermates')
        users_requests = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="users_requests")
        req_bio = models.CharField(max_length=400)
        req_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='requestmates_pics', null=True, blank=True, default=False)
```

views.py

```
    def matesmain(request):
        contents = Mates.objects.all()
        context = {
            'contents': contents,
            'form_mates': MatesForm(),
        }
        print("nice")
        return render(request, 'mates.html', context)
```

css

```
    .mates-grid-1-1-content {
        display: grid;
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;
        align-self: center;
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 2;
        grid-template-columns: 15% 70% 15%;
        grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
        height: 100%;
        grid-auto-flow: column;
    }
    .mates-grid-2-content {
        grid-column:1;
        justify-content: center;
        align-self: center;
    }
    .mates-grid-3-content {
        grid-column:3;
        justify-content: center;
        align-self: center;
    }
    .mates-grid-1-content {
        display: grid;
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;
        align-self: center;
        grid-column: 2;
        grid-template-columns: 70px 28% 28%;
        grid-template-rows: .1fr 5fr;
        height: 95%;
        grid-auto-flow: row;

    }
```

Comment: There are tons of options depending on what you exactly want to do, you should explain more. Do you want the data to be random? Do you want to slide by button click? Do you want to load without reloading the page etc. So we can help you understand what you should learn.

Comment: @mattarello sorry, let me explain more;)

Comment: @mattarello I just updated it, can you please check it now?

Comment: Okay then, first of all to load content without refresing the page you have to use ajax, which is pretty simple if you know jquery. If you don't know jquery is a simplified version of javascript that you can easily learn on youtube, not much is required so do not be afraid of it. Once you solve the ajax side (getting info from database without refresing) you'll need to be able to clean the user container, smth like "container.empty", and append previous and next buttons the function with the id of user you want to get. If I were you I'd start by spending couple of hours on learning jquery.

Comment: @mattarello can you help me with an answer please?

Comment: Sure, share your model (if it's not custom user model) and the view please.

Comment: @mattarello I just added the models.py and views.py files so that you can check them! I really hope that helps

Comment: @mattarello I also added the css;)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to add jquery to your project, just google it it's pretty simple, get the latests version out.

I assume you want to order the users by their id's, say current user's id is 5 than next one's id will be 6 and so on.

your buttons should look like:

```
 <button type="button" onclick="previous({{user.id}})"   id="prev-button">prev</button>
 <button type="button"  onclick="next({{user.id}})" id="next-button">next</button>
```

So the button will trigger ajax functions and pass them current users id so you can work with it in view side. I'll write only one for you to get the idea.

```
function previous(id){
    $.ajax({
            url: 'here you write the url to the view function',
            type: "get",
            data: {
                'id': id,
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                   "first clean the elements to which you want to append new element as an example:"
           $(".mates-item-content").empty();
           $(".mates-item-content").append("<img class="mate-pic" src="new one you got from database" >")
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('nope');
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Above you see the ajax structure for jquery, it basically sends the info to the url you want (in our example it's the user id) and triggers the function, then it receives info from it. Afterwards in the success part you tell the function what to the with the received data.

Let's say you create a new app just for ajax functions and call it ajax. In your ajax views you should write a new function to receive data from html side. Let's call it previous again:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def previous(request):
    id= request.GET.get("id", None)
    if id != 1:
       previous_id= id-1
    prev_user= Mates.objects.filter(user= previous_id)
    "now we got the Mates model related to the previous user so you can send all the infos of it back to html"
   
   data={ 
      username= prev_user.user
      req_bio= prev_user.req_bio
      etc.
   }
     return JsonResponse(data)
```

It probably looks a bit complicated to you but trust me with just a little study on jquery and ajax you will understand it. Keep in mind that this one is just a raw guide of what you have to do, there will be lots of problems for you to solve, such as what to do if user id is 1 etc. Have fun!

Comment: this looks very wierd let me try it, to learn more about this what do you recomend?

Comment: I have 2 questions on the script part, I have to append all the elements(image, profile-picture, username and req-bio) or just the img as you have it on your code?

Comment: And for the second one, in the part that says "new one you got from database" should I put this like on the html {{ content.req_image.url }} ?

Comment: All the elements that you want, in your case it looks like you have to change every element from your last user. Think like you have a note book and you write down about your friends to every page, by turning the page you'd see info about another friend of yours. But if you have only one page you have to erase every information related to the last person and write down new ones information. erase ---> emtpy() and write --> append in your case.

Comment: so I would have to repeat `.empty` and `.append` as many times I need right?

Comment: I really like encouraging people like you but I can't write down the whole project for you. So you should search how you receive data by ajax. In the example above view function sends back a json object (data), find a way to use it :) Yes as many times as you need.

Comment: Ok thankyou! I have lots of questions because as I said before, I am new at this